# Elasticsearch: Aggregate all unique values of a field and apply a condition or filter by another field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

My documents look like this:

```
{
    "ownID": "Val_123",
    "parentID": "Val_456",
    "someField": "Val_78",
    "otherField": "Val_90",
     ...
}
```

I am trying to get all (unique, as in one instance) results for a list of **ownID** values, while filtering by a list of **parentID** values and vice-versa.

What I did so far is:

- Get (separate!) unique values for **ownID** and **parentID** in *key1* and *key2*

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "key1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ownID",
        "include": {
          "partition": 0,
          "num_partitions": 10
        },
        "size": 100
      }
    },
    "key2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "parentID",
        "include": {
          "partition": 0,
          "num_partitions": 10
        },
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- Use filter to get (some) results matching either **ownID** OR **parentID**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "ownID": ["Val_1","Val_2","Val_3"]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "parentID": ["Val_8","Val_9"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_filter": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 30000,
        "_source": {
          "include": ["ownID", "parentID","otherField"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I need to get **separate** results for each filter in the second query, and get:

- **(1)** the **parentID** of the documents matching some value of **ownID**
- **(2)** the **ownID** for the documents matching some value of **parentID**.

So far I managed to do it using two similar queries (see below for **(1)**), but I would ideally want to combine them and query only once.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "ownID": [ "Val1", Val_2, Val_3 ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_filter": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 30000,
        "_source": {
          "include": "parentID"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Elasticsearch version 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly then you need to get all the aggregations count correct irrespective of the filter query but in search hits you want the filtered documents only, so for this elasticsearch has another type of filter : "post filter" : refer to this : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-post-filter.html

its really simple, it will just filter the results after the aggregations have been computed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried implementing it, however the post_filter is applied on hits, while I get my (selective fields) results in aggs. Also, I wasn't able to use a list of values for the filter terms. I've been using Elasticsearch for a relatively short period so I might have some limitations in understanding how to use everything. I hope it's not to much to ask, but could you elaborate a bit on my use case?

Comment: do you want the results of a term aggregation to be used as a filter condition? if thats the case then its better that you fir one aggregation query and then a separate filter query as filters are also cached so that will have a performance benefit also.